# Bluestacks as Android emulator - error while running app

Tags: windows, android-studio, bluestacks

I want to use Bluestacks as android studio emulator, but when I try to run app I get this error:

> com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: unknown command 'SEND' (444e4553) 
>   Error while Installing APK

I tried adb kill and start server, reinstalling Bluestacks, but nothing helps

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it. I had trouble finding an up-to-date Q&A thread so I am glad you asked this question in 2019.

As of 2019, two meaningful changes have occurred that you need to look out for.

1. Bluestacks has now INTENTIONALLY BLOCKED adb connections out-of-the-box
2. Android Studio has introduced instant run feature, which may be kinda broken in different development setups

You should check issue 1 first before moving on to checking issue 2

Instructions for issue 1:

Open bluestacks. Find the actual settings for the bluestacks program itself, which is a gear symbol in the grey bar at the top. To do this, select the gear icon, the click "settings". click the preferences tab then make sure "Enable Android Debug Bridge (ADB)" is checked. This should be unchecked by default in newest version of bluestacks.

Instructions for issue 2:

Go to android studio. From the menu items at the top. Click File->Settings, which opens a dialog. Click the "Build, Execution, Deployment" item on the left. THis will expand and you will see "instant run" as a sub option. Click it, then make sure the "enable instant run" checkbox on the right is unchecked.

Finally, as some side pointers:

- Always open bluestacks first before android studio. This avoids the need for any adb commands. If you for got this, then do the adb kill-server, adb start-server, but don't forget to run adb connect localhost:5555 after you have killed then started the adb server. Since the sdk/platform-tools is usally in a very strange appdata location, I recommend adding the sdk/platform-tools folder to your path.
- I have not tested whether it is actually necessary to disable instant run, if you make sure adb is enabled on bluestacks. You may need to test this for yourself. However I do not know if instant-run is that beneficial so I jsut choose to not use it just in case.